# Start closing event on form 1 from form 2

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form 1 design with a Close button on it,when the close button is pressed u get a textbox and an ok button on another form (form 2),when u enter the password 1234 in the textbox and press the ok button I want it to close the form 2 and , close and e.cancel = false; the form 1 because e.cancel = true; in the Form1_FormClosing method.

## Form 1

```
   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {                   
           e.Cancel = true;
   }
```

## Form 2

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
private void password_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 mc = new Form2();
    mc.MyProperty = textBox1.Text;

    if (textBox1.Text == "1234")
    {             
        Close();              
    }
    else
    {               

    }
}
```

Bottom line, I want something like

```
 if (textBox1.Text == "1234")
 {      
    Close();
    e.Cancel=false;
    Form1.Close();
 }
```

Don't hate me if it's easy to do but I'm really new to C# programming.

Comment: what is `Close();` ?

Comment: command line to Close the form.

Comment: why command line, any specific reason ?

Comment: and it closes my form 2 automatically after the condition is fulfilled

Comment: i don't want the user to be able to close the form until he enters the password.

Comment: what i understood is, on `form1` closing event you asking for password from  `form2`, if password is correct close 'form1' else not. am i right ?

Comment: close form1 and form 2,but before u can close form 1 u need to e.Cancel = false; because if not you cannot close the form1 any possible way .But yea u got the idea right :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this

on `form1`

```
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }
```

on `form2`

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "12345")
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: check for password you entered, i have given '12345'

Comment: yep,I typed in the right password,and as I said Form2 is closing but Form1 is not,and I think because the e.Cancel must be false and u wrote true,but I tried with both values true and false and it's not working.

Comment: on form2 put a debug point and check is your condition is going in if or else ?

Comment: its going in the if statement.

Comment: is your `form1` is called from any other form ?

Comment: nope,I have only form1 main form and form2 child form and form1 is never called in form 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113600/discussion-between-john-pietrar-and-pranav-patel).

Answer (score 1):

on form1 :

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
            f2.ShowDialog();
        }        
    }
}
```

On form2 :

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        Form1 frm;
        public Form2(Form1 frm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.frm = frm;
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox1.Text == "12345")
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                this.Close();
                frm.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosingFalse);
               frm.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                this.Close();
                frm.FormClosing += new System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosingTrue);

            }
        }

        public void Form1_FormClosingTrue(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        public void Form1_FormClosingFalse(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Cancel = false ;
        }
    }
```